# vertically tile image in background using layer-list

Tags: android, android-layout

I have set the background of my app using xml like this in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/leftImage" >
        </bitmap>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/rightImage"
            android:tileMode="repeat" >
        </bitmap>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

what i want to do is to tile the two to images vertically, so that i have two edges tiled vertically one to the right and other to the left.

the tile mode i found tiles both vertically and horizontally, I need the images to be tiled vertically only.

Is there a way to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this programmatically (as far as I know there is no way to do this via XML):

```
BitmapDrawable bg = new BitmapDrawable(
         BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.your_resource));

bg.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

something.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
```

Note that there are other ways to create a `BitmapDrawable` - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html.